# How to migrate the data to different cluster in cluster version of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I has just recently expanded Apache IoTDB from standalone version to cluster version. I now want to copy the data of cluster A to cluster B. Since for standalone version, I only need to copy the data directory to achieve this data migration process, I want to know do I only need to copy the tsfile of cluster A to automatically import the data into cluster B? If the process suitable for standalone version changed, I want to know what do I need to do to migrate data in cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standalone version of Apache IoTDB, you can migrate data by directly copying the data folder. Howver, data migration cannot be done like this with cluster version. If you want to migrate your data from cluster to cluster, the enterprise version of IoTDB includes cluster migration functions, incremental backup and full backup.